# Spring Boot Context Path Static Files Not Found

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, static-content, contextpath

I have a problem with my application not finding my static files. This however only happens on a certain level. As you can see from the code fragments below, the css, images, js, etc works on certain files and not on others. Not sure what I am missing here.

My Stack: Spring Boot, Thymeleaf

Part of my application.yml file:

```
server:
  port: 8090
  servlet:
    context-path: /myapp
```

My application public resources directory structure:

```
/resources
   /public
      /css
      /images
      /js
```

My application template structure and where the styles and images work:

```
/resources
  /templates/index.html (works)
  /templates/admin/index.html (works)
  /templates/admin/user/admin/showuser.html (does not work)
```

Code from /resources/admin/fragments/header.html (Used as a header file for other files)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Code from /resources/templates/index.html  (works) (Does not include the header.html fragment)

```
<link href="css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Code from /resources/templates/admin/index.html  (works) (Includes header.html as a fragment using Thymeleaf)

```
<!--/*/ <th:block th:include="/admin/fragments/header"></th:block> /*/-->
```

Code from /resources/templates/admin/user/admin/showuser.html  (does not work) (Includes header.html as a fragment using Thymeleaf)

```
<!--/*/ <th:block th:include="/admin/fragments/header"></th:block> /*/-->
```

Not sure how to fix this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your urls *don't* begin with a slash `/`, they attempt to resolve the current directory.  For example:

```
Page: /templates/index.html
Css:  css/mycss.css

The browser tries to locate /templates/css/mycss.css
```

If the cases that don't work:

```
Page: /templates/admin/user/admin/showuser.html
Css:  css/mycss.css

The browser tries to locate /templates/admin/user/admin/css/mycss.css
```

If you want to make sure your css works everywhere, you need to make sure the link points consistently to the correct location.  I'm guessing something like this would work:

```
<link th:href="@{/css/mycss.css}" rel="stylesheet">
```

(Using Thymeleaf to add the context, and to make the path absolute.)

Comment: You are absolutely 100% correct with the Thymeleaf solution. After adding it to all my links everything works great. Thanks.